# Want to create a custom function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am working on a CakePHP 2.x .. I want to create a special class in which I want to create functions so that I can call functions from other controllers.

For example this function

```
function replace_dashes($string) {
   $string = str_replace("-", " ", $string);
  return $string;
     }
```

So whenever I want to use that function in some other controller I can call this or can pass parameters too ...

I want to implement all the raw functions like this in some class. How can I do this in CakePHP?

Comment: You want to create a class with helper methods? Use a lib in /Lib for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not that difficult. Just create a file in /Lib, ideally with a namespace like "Utility":

```
/Lib/Utility/Utility.php
```

and put your methods in there:

```
class Utility {
    public static function replaceDashes($string) { ... }
}
```

Then you can use it anywhere in your app:

```
//App::uses('ClassName', 'Package'); and our Package is the Folder "Utility" in /Lib
App::uses('Utility', 'Utility');
$result = Utility::replaceDashes($input);
```

etc

See https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/Utility/Utility.php
and its test case for a real life scenario/example.

Don't forget to write a few test cases for, as well.

Comment: If there's a natural namespace the "Lib" directory is actually unnecessary. i.e. `App/Utility/Utility.php` is more logical (and Cake checks for this before the libs folder which is a fallback).

Comment: I guess it comes back to preference. If you have like 20 namespaces the APP folder might be become more and more unreadable. I like to stick to /Lib personally. But yeah, it is a very valid point that this is also possible to do.

Answer (score -3):

Create this function in your AppContoller.php like

```
public function __replaceDashes($string) {
       $string = str_replace("-", " ", $string);
       return $string;
 }
```

Call this in any controller like

```
$str = "anything";
$your_output = $this->__replaceDashes($str);
```

OR

You can make your own component.

Comment: well i dont want to write this into app controller as already i have a lot important code there

Comment: Then make a component for your custom function or use lib

Comment: i dont know how to i do this .. can you provide me a sample example or any useful link

Comment: dont know how to make a component