# Where to put universal functionality in a CakePHP project

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, dry, helper

I currently have a Helper (`FieldFormatterHelper`) I created to assist with consistent formatting of certain types of data (dates, booleans, enumerated types, etc) across various views.

In particular I store certain enumerated types in MySQL using an integer and then display a corresponding string value in my views.  The problem I'm running into now is that while this Helper works well for my views for things like "view" and "index" Views that administrative users access from the site's backend, I also have `afterSave()` methods in several models that create JSON outputs for Mustache rendering on the frontend.

I understand, more or less, the core ideas of MVC and the basic arguments for, say, not trying to access a View Helper from within a Model, but I need some sort of universal access to the functionality my Helper provides.  Certainly I could define my enumerated type mappings in my frontend JavaScript and other places I might need it, but that violates the DRY principle and would ultimately be a pain to maintain.

So, the question is: **If it's not appropriate to access/load my Helper from within my Model, where, and how, should I encapsulate this functionality so both my Models and various Views can utilize it?**

Ideally, I would be able to continue using my existing `FieldFormatterHelper`--perhaps modifying to be a wrapper for this new container.

Any guidance on the ways of CakePHP and MVC in general would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Pretty similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448380/want-to-create-a-custom-function/17448960#17448960

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it as a static method on a class and use it anywhere

```
 class Utils {
     static public function formatField($args) {
          // your implementation
     } 
 }
```

then just have your helper defer to the static method call using

```
 Utils::formatField($args);
```

Comment: What's the best way to work with this solution that allows me to maintain my copious instance-based references to the current helper in my many, many views?

Comment: Move the code from your helper into the static function and replace with a call to the static function. Helper instances and calls will remain intact and you can use the functionality throughout all portions of your application.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense.  I will give it a whirl and, assuming it works (and I suspect it will), I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static function and put it in app\view\helper\AppHelper.php. Then when you want to call it you put

`App::uses('AppHelper','View/Helper');`

at the top of the file and call it like this:

`AppHelper::staticFunction()`